# how to enable keyboard focus for selected item in listview?

Tags: listview, uwp, focus, winui

i have a winui/uwp app with a listview, when i use keyboard for navigate between items there is a white border around selected item, how i can enable this border for selected item by default? so i dont need to use keyboard. i dont want to use BorderThickness/BorderBrush in my ItemTemplate. i just want to enable keyboard focus by default
[image]

Comment: Try to call Control.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard) when the selection is changed.

Comment: @emoacht tnx fixed

Comment: Does @Andrew's solution works?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT no i used FocusState.Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Naming your `ListView`, getting the selected item container, then setting [Focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.focus?view=winrt-22621#:%7E:text=You%20typically%20pass,key%20press%20handler.) should work.

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int selectedIndex = this.ListViewControl.SelectedIndex;

    if (this.ListViewControl.ContainerFromIndex(selectedIndex) is UIElement selectedElement)
    {
        selectedElement.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
}
```